# System.NullReferenceException: VisualBasic issue with Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, exception

I'm having issues with my code and the objective is that I want it to send to a DataGridView a "product" when you click on the image of said "product" but it gives me this error:

```
    Private Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
        s1 = s1 + 1
        If s1 = 0 Then
            s1 = 1
            Compras.DataGridView3.Rows.Add("1", " Paracetamol")
        ElseIf s1 = 1 Then
            s1 = 0
            For Each fila As DataGridViewRow In Compras.DataGridView3.Rows
                If fila.Cells(1).Value = " Paracetamol" Then
                    Compras.DataGridView3.Rows.Remove(fila)
                End If
            Next


        End If
```

Compras - Is the form where its located
fila - means line in Spanish (need this because my teacher only speaks Spanish)
How do I fix this or is there a way to create a checkout easier?
Thanks for the help!

I tried maybe deleting the "filas" part and just putting "compras" but nope also read the article that Microsoft has but not much of a help (sorry for having a smooth brain)

The error pop up is

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
FarRanita.Compras.DataGridView3.get returned Nothing.

Comment: Assuming you're working on winforms here.  The question is how you created DataGridView3?  The error would suggest that DataGridView3 doesn't exist, but if that was the case, I would expect you to be getting compile errors.  Is Compras the same form you're triggering this event from?  If not, I would suspect the issue is around how you're creating a reference to that form instance

Comment: It's not clear which line the error occurs on. Add code to check if `DataGridView3` is Nothing. If so, output an error message: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error DataGridView3 is Nothing")`. The issue may be your use of `For Each`. Try using `For` instead.